# Jmeter Report Generation

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

i'm new to performance testing especially in jmeter

my question is, is there any alternative beside HTML Dashboard report for generating report in jmeter?

i'm wondering is there any other alternative so i could pick what extension or plugin for generating report that meets my requirements

Thank you for your attention and answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. JMeter's [.jtl result files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) are basically [CSV files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) so you can use [Excel](https://www.office.com/launch/Excel) or equivalent to make tables/charts you want.
2. You can open results file with the [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) of your choice (including [plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Graphs)) and save the tables or charts as CSV or PNG files
3. Basically the same as point 2 but unattended and automated: [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeterpluginscmd)
4. [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) framework comes with [Existing Results Loader](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ResultsLoader/) executor which allows uploading test results to [BlazeMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/) platform where you can analyze and export them